# CompileDaemon "command not found" Not using docker

Tags: linux, go, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hade CompileDaemon working in my golang app before, but it stopped working on my WSL Ubuntu. I tried everything to get it working, and then reinstalled WSL switching to Debian. I am not using docker.  I then tried things again and it still says command not found even after installing it two different ways:

```
go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
go: added github.com/fatih/color v1.9.0
go: added github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.9
go: added github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon v1.4.0
go: added github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.4
go: added github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.11
go: added github.com/radovskyb/watcher v1.0.7
go: added golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20191026070338-33540a1f6037
```

OR

`go install -mod=mod github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon`

Then when I run  CompileDaemon --command="./folder_name"

**returns:**
bash: CompileDaemon: command not found

Comment: `CompileDaemon` is not in your PATH. `go install` will put it in GOBIN, which is by default `GOPATH/bin`. GOPATH by default is `$HOME/go`.

Comment: @JimB thanks for the tip,  is there a way to make that command work anywhere in the command line or do I always need to reference the full path to compiledaemon?  when I first installed it, it was working fine with just CompileDaemon  and then after a few days it stopped working

Comment: If you want binaries in `GOBIN` to be accessible in your search `PATH`, then you need to add that directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: I tried adding the path to CompileDaemon to path, using the export option in /etc/profile ... I must be doing something wrong because that still doesn't work  

In order to run the CompileDaemon Currently I am running:  inside the "\home\jason\go\project"

../bin/CompileDaemon --command="./project"

Answer (score 7):

I face the same issue, here is how I solve it.
It seems that GOPATH is not added to ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE as expected.

```
vim ~/.zshrc

...
export GOPATH="$HOME/go" # set GOPATH (path to where go is installed)
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin # append GOPATH to PATH
```

don't forget to

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: for looking path of "$HOME/go", you guys can replace $HOME/go with `export GOPATH="Users/yourname/go"`

Answer (score 1):

- Try running `go env GOPATH` to see where your Go workspace is located. Mine was in `/root/go`
- Then you can try running `ls` the path e.g `ls /root/go` to see if the executable file is located there.
- If it is not located there, you can try running `go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon` to install it again. Let me know if that helps.
- Finally run `GOPATH/bin/CompileDaemon` in my own case  `/root/go/bin/CompileDaemon`.

**Note**:
You can include your flag e.g `-command="./directory"`.
You must be in where you initialize your go.mod or current module for your go program